# Access local mysql server with shiny.io

Tags: r, rmysql, shiny

I'm trying to create shiny app in shiny.io which requires access to a MySQL database which is located in my local machine. Is it possible to use RMySQL to connect to the local database by shiny.io? And how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a little "late" with my answer, but keep in mind that if you are deploying to shiny.io then "localhost" is pointing to shiny.io and there is no mysql for you there :-) So you should have to open your MySQL server and use your public IP address in "host" variable. Not that I am proposing this, from the security point of view it is not wise to open your MySQL server to the public. If you follow this way, at least, you should filter connections to only allow the IP address of shiny.io.

Another solution -more reasonable, in my opinion- might be to use an already public server that offers you a persistence layer, such as mongohq.com (now [compose.io](http://compose.io)). They use MongoDB (not MySQL) but it could satisfy your needs (and you will get a 512MB RAM testing server for free). You may want to study [this working example that uses shiny.io and mongo](http://www.r-bloggers.com/using-mongohq-to-build-a-shiny-hit-counter/) in order to start your project up.

Answer (score 0):

The usage is essentially the same as in regular R script.
you can put this at the top of your server.R file

```
library(RMySQL)
con = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='myusername', password='mysillypassword', db='dataaa', host='localhost')

query = "SELECT 1"
result = dbGetQuery(con, query)
```

Now result will be available for the rest of the shiny app.

You can also build the query inside a reactive function, and dynamically query the database.

Comment: Instead of storing the mysql username and password in a script, it is recommended to store them in an option file. For example, you can store the password in the mysql configuration file of the shiny user: /home/shiny/.my.cnf on the server. See also: [MySQL using option files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html), and  [MariaDB configuring my.cnf](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/configuring-mariadb-with-mycnf/).

Answer (score 0):

Within your mySQL database, **whitelist shinyapps.io IP addresses**.

See this [helpful post from Rstudio support](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217592507-How-do-I-give-my-application-on-shinyapps-io-access-to-my-remote-database-#).